# PHP MySQL syntax error in script but statement works when typed directly into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I've written a MySQL query which works fine when passed directly to the MySQL console however when I try to run the query in a php script, I get this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE week_rough_stats( id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, week INT NOT NULL' at line 1

The section of php code is:

```
$sql = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS week_rough_stats; CREATE TABLE week_rough_stats( id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, week INT NOT NULL, qty INT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id) ) ENGINE = InnoDB; INSERT INTO week_rough_stats(WEEK, qty) SELECT WEEKOFYEAR(epcr_usage_rough.date) AS r_week, SUM(epcr_usage_rough.qty_epcr) AS r_qty FROM epcr_usage_rough GROUP BY r_week; SELECT YEAR(incidents_attended.dtg) AS q_year, WEEKOFYEAR(incidents_attended.dtg) AS q_week, IF( COUNT(epcr_usage.cad_ref) = 0, ANY_VALUE(week_rough_stats.qty), COUNT(epcr_usage.cad_ref) ) AS finalised_epcr, COUNT(incidents_attended.cad) AS qty_incidents, ( ( IF( COUNT(epcr_usage.cad_ref) = 0, ANY_VALUE(week_rough_stats.qty), COUNT(epcr_usage.cad_ref) ) / COUNT(incidents_attended.cad) ) * 100 ) AS compliance FROM incidents_attended LEFT JOIN epcr_usage ON incidents_attended.cad = epcr_usage.cad_ref LEFT JOIN epcr_usage_rough ON CONCAT_WS( '-', YEAR(incidents_attended.dtg), MONTH(incidents_attended.dtg), DAYOFMONTH(incidents_attended.dtg) ) = DATE(epcr_usage_rough.date) LEFT JOIN week_rough_stats ON WEEKOFYEAR(epcr_usage_rough.date) = week_rough_stats.week GROUP BY q_year ASC, q_week ASC";
    if($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {    
       $result_hdr = $conn->query($sql);
    }else{    
       echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error; exit;
    }
    while($row_hdr = $result_hdr->fetch_assoc()) {  
       $end = getEndDate($row_hdr['q_week'], $row_hdr['q_year']);
       echo "<th>$end</th>";
```

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can only execute one query at a time.

Comment: If you are using the `mysqli_` API look at `multi_query()`

Comment: @juergend That's not true

Comment: Try surrounding table names and column names with `\`` sign